# Work with the references of different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

The idea of this code is to launch it from a workbook called "`My list.xlsx`" and create a list on the Sheet "`FX`" of My List; this list would be based on spreadsheet of another already opened workbook called "`Daily prices.xlsm`".

When I try to play around, it seems that it doesn't like the way I reference the list on the other workbook to copy it. Here is my code:

```
Sub forEachWs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRowDestination As Long
    Dim ExRateWb As Workbook
    Dim DailyPrices As Workbook

    Set ExRateWb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set DailyPrices = Workbooks("Daily prices.xlsm")
    Set dest = Worksheets("FX")

    For Each ws In DailyPrices.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "FX", "BBG prices", "PRICES"

            Case Else

                MsgBox DailyPrices.Name

                LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                LastRowDestination = dest.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2

                DailyPrices.ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 5)).Copy
                ExRateWb.dest.Cells(LastRowDestination, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _ 
                                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line does it flag the error?

Answer (score 0):

As [kaybee99 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820436/work-with-the-references-of-different-workbooks/29823380#comment47768864_29820436), you don't indicate exactly where the issue occurs, but I do see a couple of potential areas for error that I'll note above the offending line:

```
Sub forEachWs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRowDestination As Long
    Dim ExRateWb As Workbook
    Dim DailyPrices As Workbook
```

The assumption is that this will be pointing at the workbook in which this code resides. However, there is no guarantee of that this is still the case, since other code (not shown in your OP) may have used `<workbook>.Select` which would have changed what the `ActiveWorkbook` is

```
    Set ExRateWb = ActiveWorkbook
```

> Using this method to set your "workbook" variable is much better, because it's guaranteed to be accurate no matter what workbook is currently active - this is the preferred method of assigning your `Workbook` variables.

```
    Set DailyPrices = Workbooks("Daily prices.xlsm")
```

Your worksheet is assumed to be in the `ActiveWorkbook`, again, no guarantee that whatever is currently the active workbook will have an `FX` worksheet. Recommend changing this to `Set Dest = ExRateWb.Worksheets("FX")` or `Set Dest = DailyPrices.WorkSheets("FX")` as appropriate

```
    Set dest = Worksheets("FX")

    For Each ws In DailyPrices.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "FX", "BBG prices", "PRICES"
```

I'd suggest putting at least a comment in here acknowledging that you are intentionally doing nothing for these three worksheets. Helps prevent concern for the next time you (or someone else) is through your code & wonders what was accidentally deleted...

```
            Case Else
                MsgBox DailyPrices.Name
                LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                LastRowDestination = dest.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2
```

`DailyPrices` is a Workbook variable containing a collection of Worksheets that you've already referenced in your `For Each...` statement that created the loop you're currently in. Referencing it again will be invalid. `ws` is the reference to the current (in this loop) worksheet in the `DailyPrices` Workbook. Remove the `DailyPrices.` reference below

```
                DailyPrices.ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 5)).Copy
```

Similar to the above comments, `Dest` has already been defined as Worksheet belonging to a specific workbook, so the `ExRateWb` qualifier is unnecessary and, in fact, invalid. Remove it.

```
                ExRateWb.dest.Cells(LastRowDestination, 1).PasteSpecial _
                           Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _ 
                           SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

If these changes don't address the issue, please specify exactly where it is you're getting an error, and exactly what the error is.